# How to prevent columns overflowing modal with Bulma CSS Framework

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

The problem is fully illustrated by [this minimal example on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZRaez?editors=1000)

To restate however: the Bulma CSS framework provides a columns container and a modal element. If one is placed inside the other, as in the following complete code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal is-active">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
      <header class="modal-card-head">
        <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
        <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-card-body">
        <div id="my-columns" class='columns is-mobile'>
          <div class='column'>
            <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
          </div>
          <div class='column'>
            <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
        <button class="button">Cancel</button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Then the .columns element takes the width of the parent, but the .column s inside it overflow the modal to the right.

Does anyone know why this is and how to stop it happening? It's a flexbox issue for sure, but CSS is not really my domain. Any comments about what information is needed to make this question more generally applicable (in terms of the css used inside the Bulma framework) are welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that a *block like* element, as e.g. `display: flex` is, it won't grow larger than its parent, hence cause this overflow.

If you make the `#my-columns` to be *inline-flex* it will work, using `is-inline-flex`.

Stack snippet

```css
#my-columns {
  background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="modal is-active">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
      <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
    </header>
    <div class="modal-card-body">
      <div id="my-columns" class='columns is-mobile is-inline-flex'>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
      <button class="button">Cancel</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Another option would be to make it break line, using `is-multiline`

Stack snippet

```css
#my-columns {
  background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="modal is-active">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
      <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
    </header>
    <div class="modal-card-body">
      <div id="my-columns" class='columns is-mobile is-multiline'>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
          <button class='button is-primary'>Some Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
      <button class="button">Cancel</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes - indeed, I was being a total idiot too, because Bulma has a .is-multiline attribute to achieve this. Do you want to add that to the top of this answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @N.McA. Updated with 2 samples, one properly overflow, one wrapping to new line